# C++ - Output always pushes to the most left?

Tags: c++

The `fiboEncoding()` function below is to read an integer then return the Fibonacci encoding.

When I test it in the main function, it always pushes itself into the most left part of the output. How can I solve this problem? What did I do wrong to cause this problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

string fiboEncoding(int n) {
    string word;
    int fib[1000];
    fib[0] = 1;
    fib[1] = 2;
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 2; fib[i-1] <= n; i++) {
        fib[i] = fib[i-1] + fib[i-2];
    }
    
    int r = i - 2;
    int index = r;
    vector<char> v(r+3);
    
    while(n > 0) {
        v[index] = '1';
        n = n - fib[index];
        index = index - 1;
        while (index >= 0 && fib[index] > n) {
            v[index] = '0';
            index = index - 1;
        }
    }
    v[r + 1] = '1';
    
    for (int j = 0; j < v.size() - 1; j++) {
        cout << v[j];
    }
    return word;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    string fibo;
    cin >> n;
    fibo = fiboEncoding(n);
    cout << "code: " << fibo << endl;
}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Please do some [*rubber duck debugging*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of your `fiboEncoding` function. What does it do? What does it *output*? And what does it return? Then think about what (if anything) it should output, and what (if anything) it should return.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Did you maybe inherit Sam's rubber duck?

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns an empty string word. You forgot to copy the result into word string.
What you see in the console is the result of executing the following part not cout.

```
for (int j = 0; j < v.size() - 1; j++) {
    cout << v[j];
}
```

To fix replace the above for loop by

```
for (int j = 0; j < v.size() - 1; j++) {
    //cout << v[j];
    word += v[j];
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Ashkan, you really saved my day!